# Super basic logistic regression example

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am new to ML and I created a super basic logistic regression example with 4 points on the $x$ line that belong to two classes:

```
points = [[1, 1]]
points = points + [[2, 0]] 
points = points + [[1.5, 1]]
points = points + [[2.5, 0]]

data   = np.array([x[:-1] for x in points])
target = [int(x[-1]) for x in points]

alg = LogisticRegression()
alg.fit(data, target)
print (alg.coef_)
print (alg.intercept_)

print (alg.predict_proba(1))
print (alg.predict_proba(1.5))
print (alg.predict_proba(2))
print (alg.predict_proba(2.5))
```

I expected the model to understand that anything greater than 1.5 belongs to class 0, and anything smaller than 2 belongs to class 0. However, everything is predicted to be in class 0. Also, in this case , what is the meaning for the coef and intercept? More precisely, is there a way to deduce from the coef and intercept where the model thinks the points switch from class 0 to class 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is the meaning for the coef and intercept

A (binary) logistic regression algorithm tries to determine whether the data $x$ belongs to class 0 or class 1 by the value
$f(x)=\omega x+b$. If the value $f(x)>0$, the algorithm believe $x$ is more likely to be in class 1; while if $f(x)<0$, then $x$ is more likely to be in class 0.

In your code `alg.coef_` is the $\omega$ above, and `alg.intercept_` is the $b$ above.

## Why everything is predicted to be in class 0

If you run your code, you should see the result `alg.coef_=-0.354, alg.intercept_=0.307`. Therefore your `alg` is calculating $f(x)=-0.354x+0.307$. Now if you plug in your `data`, i.e. $x=$1, 2, 1.5 and 2.5 respectively, you should get the value $f(x)=$-0.047,-0.401,-0.224 and -0.579 respectively.

As you see, all the four $f(x)$ values are smaller than 0, therefore your `alg` determines that they all belong be class 0.

## But still why? Why the result is not what I expected?

Here is were [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) comes in. In the context of logistic regression, the learning algorithm *regularizes* that the learned parameter, $w$, should not be too large. To be specific, by default it regularizes the [$l_2$ norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html) norm of $w$. In your case $w$ is a scalar, then $l_2$ norm is its absolute value.

In general, regularization is used to prevent [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). But that's another broad topic.

If you want your algorithm to behave as you expected (classify 1 and 1.5 to class 1, and classify 2 and 2.5 to class 0) , there are 2 ways.

- You tell you program to use extremely *weak* regularization. 
  That can be achieved by passing a large value to the `C` parameter in `alg = LogisticRegression()` (default value is 1.0, see [detail](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)), e.g.

```
alg = LogisticRegression(C=1000)
```

In this case your algorithm should return `alg.coef_=-9.894, alg.intercept_=17.156`, and it can classify your four data points correctly. Notice that the absotely value of `alg.coef_` is now much larger than before.

- Provide your algorithm with more data.

  For example, simply repeat your four data points 100 times:

`data   = [x[:-1] for x in points]*100
target = [int(x[-1]) for x in points]*100`

Then you can get `alg.coef_=-4.438, alg.intercept_=7.594` without setting `C`. In this case the same default regularization strength is still applied, but the additional data provide stronger evidence for your algorithm to believe that the `alg.coef_` should be allowed larger (in absolutely value).

Comment: It does calculate sigmoid(f(x)). But inside your sigmoid function f(x)=ωx+b. The sigmoid function translates f(x) into a probability.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment because I figured it out